# django get the logged in user in the form to build queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I have this model:

```
class Searches(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    .....other fields
```

Each `user` has certain saved searches. I want to display a `form`(a `choiceSelect widget`) to select one of the several searches and click go. I want to `filter` in the `form` to display only the `searches` of that particular `User`. This is what I tried. but `request.user` below does not work.  how to fix this?

This is my form:

```
class SearchesForm(forms.Form):
    #get the queryset for the searches model of logged in user
    qset=Searches.objects.filter(user=request.user) ----> error
    #get the most recent entry
    default=Searches.objects.latest('id')
    choices = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=qset,label='select search',initial=default)
```

EDIT:
my view:

```
def display_search_user(request):
    form=SearchesdiffForm(request)
    if request.method=='POST':
        search=SearchesdiffForm(request,data=request.POST)
        print search
        return HttpResponse(search)
    return render(request,'search_list.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `instance` of the queryset is created when the server starts and there is no knowledge about the `request` at that moment. The `request` is specific to each `request`

You have to pass the request to the form `__init__` when you create the form in the view:

```
class SearchesForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Searches.objects.none(),
                                     label='select search')

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if request.user:
            queryset = Searches.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        else:
            queryset = Searches.objects.all()
        latest = queryset.latest('id')
        self.fields['choices'].queryset = queryset

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchesForm(request, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # return search template here.
            return render(...)
    else:
        form = SearchesForm(request, request.POST)
    return render(request, 'template_name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Searches.objects.empty() is undefined why is that?

Comment: yep, I figured that out, and I tried, but I get `MultiValueDictKeyError`

Comment: I get 'No data received' on the browser. I used your exact code above for forms. I pasted my view in edit above

Comment: I though you know how to use the view. Mine was an example on just how to use the form in the view. You need to pass the form to the template and all.

Comment: I updated with a better `view` but you may still need to add some functionality.

Comment: how do I get what is selected in the form (after it is posted), so that I could use it in return render(...). There is a search Object that is selected from choicefield, which is in postdata. how can I retrieve that search object?

Comment: and the initial value in the form is not loading up. it is still `-------`

Comment: I fixed everything, it must be `else:
        form = SearchesForm(request)`. thats it